# JavaScript FocusEvent relatedTarget Property not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

Check the [provided article](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_focus_relatedtarget.asp) and it's [w3school code for FocusEvent relatedTarget Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_focus_relatedtarget)  code example , it's perfectly working in Google chrome and not working in Firefox. (Use console to see the bugs)

The problem is in Chrome it will say the clicked element in an `javascript alert box`

But in firefox it says in console `TypeError: event.relatedTarget is null`

Why is this happening. how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Mozilla developer network is a better source in general. http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/event.relatedTarget.html they have a link to a jsfiddle as well which works in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Personally I'm getting `Cannot read property tagName of null` in Chrome from the w3c example.

Comment: @GillesC hmm. getting that for firefox. but works fine with chrome.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
event.target.tagName
```

it works in all browsers

Comment: `event.target` and `event.relatedTarget` are different right ?

Answer (score 0):

View in console while loading the [page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_focus_relatedtarget) below the error was showing `TypeError: event.relatedTarget is null`

Comment: yeah. But if it works fine then it should pop an alert right?